# How would one digitize a thick book into a PDF version in the most time-efficient way, using only a camera and a computer?

Tags: pdf, scanner, scanning, ebook, digitization

For this example I have a:

- dSLR camera (Canon EOS) + **no** tripod
- latest commercial version of Adobe Acrobat
- a computer with internet
- frugal character

I also own a physically printed and bound book of over 600 pages I would like to convert to PDF.

What are methods/technologies/software features I can use to accomplish this

a.  without buying any new hardware, so no extra physical tools one wouldn't have lying around the house
b.  software-wise free, if at all possible
c.  obviously the whole point is with the least amount of time and effort as possible ;)

---

Additional info (rather: clarifications) from comments so far:

- I'm not planning anything illegal.
- The point of this is to make heavy or clunky books portable. No more. No less. Having the end result pleasantly readable on digital screens is the striving. With as little time and work possible -- efficiently.

Comment: Unless you want to spend forever cleaning up images, get a tripod (there are cheap ones), and build some simple fixture to position the book consistently; even better if it has something to flatten the open book.   Illuminate the pages brightly and evenly.  Square the camera with the book in all directions.  There is more setup time, but then it will save time on every image, and provide a basis for automating image cleanup.  That will have more effect on total project time and quality than anything you can do later with software.

Comment: This sounds like a veiled question asking for recommendations for software... kind of off topic. But don't you have a cell phone? My guess you want to make this searchable or index-able somehow? You can get free/near-free OCR (Optical Character Recognition) apps for Apple, Android, and Windows devices, which although they are not designed for a such a large task, will work fine.

Comment: [This](http://www.instructables.com/id/Quickly-Scan-a-Textbook-With-a-Camera/) instructable is probably the answer.  But this seems like would fit better on [LifeHacks](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com).

Comment: ... sell the camera and computer, pay someone to do it professionally with the profits :/

Comment: Do you have the rights to copying what you want to copy?

Comment: Find a library in your area that has a professional books scanner for public access and scan your book there.

Comment: @Xavierjazz As already said in the post, I own the book.

Comment: Hi. The fact that you own the book does not give you the right to copy it.

Comment: @fixer1234 What "automatic image cleanup" methods would work well for this kind of task?

Comment: @acejavelin Adobe Acrobat -- which I have -- already gives the option for OCR (which I don't specifically need for this task). I just want to make my heavy, clunky book portable. Nobody wants to open a 600-page book on planes.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Copying is not the same as redistributing. I can do what I want with my book as long as I keep it my book.

Comment: Once you have uniform images, you can use a program like Irfanview to batch process actions like cropping and other cleanup that would be the same for all images.

Answer (score -1):

Stand the book up vertical, open, on a table against a wall. Make a mark on the wall around the book so you know it is always in the same spot. You might even tape the cover to the wall. Set the camera on some other book on the table so it is pointed at the book and has both pages in view. Mark around the camera so you know it is always in the same spot. You might even tape the camera to the table so it does not move. Really taping the book to the wall and the camera to the table is best. Place a light somewhere behind and/or above the camera to illuminate the pages. Once everything is in place and the camera is focused it should be good to start taking pictures. Press the button, turn a page. Press the button, turn a page. Do this about 300 times. Then upload the images to the computer. If you get everything set up right you should be able to avoid messing with the images later. You can read as is, or make a pdf.